# calculating on specific fields with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I got a csv file with that kind of informations :

```
2013  Cat.1  10  Structure1  Code1  34.10
2014  Cat.1  25  Structure1  Code1  254.24
2013  Cat.2  250 Structure1  Code1  2456.4
2014  Cat.2  234 Structure1  Code1  2345.9
2013  Cat.1  5   Structure2  Code2  59
2013  Cat.1  1   Structure2  Code2  18
2014  Cat.1  8   Structure2  Code2  123
2014  Cat.1  1   Structure2  Code2  18
2013  Cat.2  64  Structure2  Code2  59
2013  Cat.2  8   Structure2  Code2  18
2014  Cat.2  70  Structure2  Code2  123
2014  Cat.2  11  Structure2  Code2  18
```

and the result file I would like is that kind :

```
2013  Cat.1  10         Structure1  Code1  34.10
2014  Cat.1  25         Structure1  Code1  254.24
2013  Cat.2  250        Structure1  Code1  2456.4
2014  Cat.2  234        Structure1  Code1  2345.9
2013  Cat.1  6 (5+1)    Structure2  Code2  77 (59+18)
2014  Cat.1  9 (8+1)    Structure2  Code2  141 (123+18)
2013  Cat.2  72 (64+8)  Structure2  Code2  77 (59+18)
2014  Cat.2  81 (70+11) Structure2  Code2  141 (123+18)
```

Is this possible using awk? I only have 2 different fields on this example for the second structure, but could be much more...

I'm very new to programming and awk in particular.

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Is your input strictly sorted by field? Is the data really CSV or this tab/space delimited format? If the input is really CSV then show the actual input and actual desired output format. Also show any work you have tried to accomplish this (you are generally expected to have put in some effort to solve your own problem before asking for a solution).

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

Not the full solution but may give you ideas

```
$awk  '{
    k = $1 FS $2 FS $4 FS $5
    a[k] += $3
    as[k] = as[k] ? as[k] "+" $3 : "(" $3
    b[k] += $6
    bs[k] = bs[k] ? bs[k] "+" $6 : "(" $6
  }

  END {
    for (k in a) {
      print k, a[k], as[k] ")", b[k], bs[k] ")"
    }
  }' file
```

will give you

```
2014 Cat.2 Structure2 Code2 81 (70+11) 141 (123+18)
2014 Cat.1 Structure2 Code2 9 (8+1) 141 (123+18)
2014 Cat.2 Structure1 Code1 234 (234) 2345.9 (2345.9)
2014 Cat.1 Structure1 Code1 25 (25) 254.24 (254.24)
2013 Cat.2 Structure2 Code2 72 (64+8) 77 (59+18)
2013 Cat.1 Structure2 Code2 6 (5+1) 77 (59+18)
2013 Cat.2 Structure1 Code1 250 (250) 2456.4 (2456.4)
2013 Cat.1 Structure1 Code1 10 (10) 34.1 (34.10)
```

Note that the column order changed to reuse `k` and single entry values are also wrapped with parans.  Both can be handled with little effort.

Comment: Reading your answer makes me realize how much I still can learn about awk. Great solution!

Answer (score 1):

Another awk answer, GNU awk specific. I assume you don't actually want to print out the addition formula.

```
gawk '
  { data[$1 OFS $2][$4 OFS $5][1] += $3
    data[$1 OFS $2][$4 OFS $5][2] += $6 }
  END {
    for (k1 in data) {
      for (k2 in data[k1]) {
        print k1, data[k1][k2][1], k2, data[k1][k2][2]
      }
    }
  }
' | sort -k4,5 -k2,2 -k1,1 | column -t
```

```
2013  Cat.1  10   Structure1  Code1  34.1
2014  Cat.1  25   Structure1  Code1  254.24
2013  Cat.2  250  Structure1  Code1  2456.4
2014  Cat.2  234  Structure1  Code1  2345.9
2013  Cat.1  6    Structure2  Code2  77
2014  Cat.1  9    Structure2  Code2  141
2013  Cat.2  72   Structure2  Code2  77
2014  Cat.2  81   Structure2  Code2  141
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible answer:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[ ]+"; OFS="\t";}
    NR==FNR{
        key = $1"-"$2"-"$4"-"$5
        idx[key] = idx[key]+1
        a[key][idx[key]] = $3
        c[key][idx[key]] = $6
    }
    NR!=FNR{
        key = $1"-"$2"-"$4"-"$5
        if(idx[key]==1){$1=$1; print ;next;}
        if(idx[key]<0){next;}
        line1 =" ("a[key][1]
        line2 =" ("c[key][1]
        sum1 = a[key][1]
        sum2 = c[key][1]
        for(i = 2; i< idx[key]; i++) {
            line1 = line1"+"a[key][i]
            line2 = line2"+"c[key][i]
            sum1 = sum1+a[key][i]
            sum2 = sum1+c[key][i]
        }
        sum1 = sum1 + a[key][idx[key]]
        sum2 = sum2 + c[key][idx[key]]
        line1 = sum1""line1"+"a[key][idx[key]]")" 
        line2 = sum2""line2"+"c[key][idx[key]]")" 
        print $1, $2, line1, $4, $5, line2
        idx[key] = -1
    }' inputFile inputFile
```

In this script, one ore more blanks  are interpreted as field separators (`FS="[ ]+"`). In the output, fields are separated by a tab (`OFS="\t"`).
Note that the script is called with two times `inputFile` as argument.
If your input really is a csv-file, then try exporting it with `,` as field separators and set `FS=OFS=","`.
Example output for the input given in the question:

```
2013    Cat.1   10  Structure1  Code1   34.10
2014    Cat.1   25  Structure1  Code1   254.24
2013    Cat.2   250 Structure1  Code1   2456.4
2014    Cat.2   234 Structure1  Code1   2345.9
2013    Cat.1   6 (5+1) Structure2  Code2   77 (59+18)
2014    Cat.1   9 (8+1) Structure2  Code2   141 (123+18)
2013    Cat.2   72 (64+8)   Structure2  Code2   77 (59+18)
2014    Cat.2   81 (70+11)  Structure2  Code2   141 (123+18)
```

Comment: You may benefit from defining a key for the arrays, also beware merging fields without a separator.  For example for two fields $1$2, `aaa bb` and `aa abb` etc will end up same value.

Comment: For instance, just use commas: `idx[$1,$2,$4,$5] = -1` which joins the fields with the character defined in the `SUBSEP` variable (default \034)

Comment: @glenn jackman / karakfa: Thank you for the advice. I have added a key according to your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

This one-liner will do the job:

`awk 'BEGIN{g=1;s="%4s  %5s  %-12s  %10s  %5s  %-12s\n"} f{printf s ,$1,$2,$3+a" ("a"+"$3")",$4,$5,$6+b" ("b"+"$6")";f=0;g=0} /Structure2/{a=$3;b=$6;f=g;g=1} /Structure1/{printf s,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' file`

```
2013  Cat.1  10         Structure1  Code1  34.10
2014  Cat.1  25         Structure1  Code1  254.24
2013  Cat.2  250        Structure1  Code1  2456.4
2014  Cat.2  234        Structure1  Code1  2345.9
2013  Cat.1  6 (5+1)    Structure2  Code2  77 (59+18)
2014  Cat.1  9 (8+1)    Structure2  Code2  141 (123+18)
2013  Cat.2  72 (64+8)  Structure2  Code2  77 (59+18)
2014  Cat.2  81 (70+11) Structure2  Code2  141 (123+18)
```

I added a formatting for the alignment, I've used 12 (`%-12s`) for the third and the sixth columns - you can increase it if the numbers go higher.